# wildcard function in Makefile without '*' or '?'

Tags: makefile

As I know $wildcard function in Makefile is used to expand * or ?. For example,

```
$(wildcard *.c)
```

is expanded to all files with extenstion .c.
but in linux Makefile I see many instances of wildcard function without * or ?.  For example

```
ARCH_POSTLINK := $(wildcard $(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile.postlink)
```

Why can't we just do

```
ARCH_POSTLINK := $(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile.postlink
```

? I don't think $(srctree) and $(SRCARCH) is expanded to multiple values here.

Comment: Are you sure neither of the variables `srctree` or `SRCARCH` contain wildcard symbols when expanded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to expanding globbing characters, `wildcard` can be used to determine if a file exists.

```
ARCH_POSTLINK := $(wildcard $(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile.postlink)
```

Here `ARCH_POSTLINK` is set to `$(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile.postlink` if and only if that file exists; else it's set to the empty string.

```
ARCH_POSTLINK := $(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile.postlink
```

Here `ARCH_POSTLINK` is set to `$(srctree)/arch/$(SRCARCH)/Makefile.postlink` regardless of whether that file exists or not.